# cimg draw_text memory leak when changing font size

Tags: memory-leaks, cimg

I am using CImg to draw a simple rectangle containing some text of a user defined size.

To do this I use draw_text on an empty CImg as it allocates an image of the exact size to contain the text.

However it is leaking memory each time I change the font size.  Any ideas on why it is leaking memory?

```
CImg<unsigned char> imgtext;
const unsigned char textColor[] = {foreground.r,foreground.g,foreground.b};
const unsigned char textBackgroundColor[] = {background.r,background.g,background.b};
imgtext.draw_text(0,0,label.c_str(),textColor, textBackgroundColor, 1.0F, fontSize);
```

Comment: This was a bug in the CImg library that the maintainer has now fixed